# Github commit count

Tags: git, firefox, github, mercurial, mozilla

How does Github count commits in a repository?
In comparing the Github gecko-dev vs mercurial repository, (https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev, and https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central) commit count (gecko-dev to me appears to be a mirror of the mozilla-central repository specifically), Github shows ~475k commits, while based on cloning the mercurial repository and doing `hg log --format="%H" | wc` or the eqivalent, or just by looking at the revision numbers, there only appear to be about ~298k commits.

What accounts for this difference?  Does Github count commits in branches that log just on the master branch doesn't?  Or is this a mirror of more than just mozilla-central?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think one is a clone of the other. If you look at branches and tags you see substantial differences. I think GitHub just counts all commits of all branches that are in the repository.

Comment: Hmm, right at the top of the github page, it states "Read-only Git mirror of the Mercurial gecko repositories at https://hg.mozilla.org".  And looking at the top-level directories and most recent commits, they appear to be the same.

Comment: Well, maybe is the main branch in sync? But look at the tags and branches.